# Bison grammar that accepts every prefix of a defined language

Tags: parsing, bison

I try to write a parser for Haskell language with the additional caveat that the program parsed can be any prefix of any valid Haskell source code.

For example this is valid source in my case:

```
func x = (x +
```

There is a BNF-like specification for Haskell here: https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/syntax-iso.html#sect9.5 .

Is there a schematic way to convert BNF grammar to a bison grammar accepting such a prefix language?

The context of this exercise is Emacs editor and source code is program being written, the goal is to provide indentation hints as the programmer writes the source code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's fairly straight-forward to take a CFG and transform it into a CFG for the language that matches all prefixes:

- for every non-terminal, add an additional -prefix version of the non-terminal
- for every rule of the form `X := A B C`, add rules of the form `X_prefix := A B C_prefix | A B | A B_prefix | A | A_prefix`
- delete all the rules that refer to `terminal_prefix`, and then recursively for `Y_prefix` where `Y_prefix` has no rules left.

Of course, this new CFG might not be LALR(1) so can't easily be used directly by bison -- you may need to refactor it to make it LALR(1), or use a GLR parser with appropriate merging rules.

Comment: Looks like a good idea. We kind of information should all these XX_prefix productions return?

Comment: Whatever you want them to return -- the basic shift-reduce parser just recognizes if a string is in the language described or not.  You can use bison's semantic information to build an AST corresponding to the parse, or any other data structure you want.

Comment: This answers my question so accepted the answer. It is still unclear to me what to return from these _prefix rules, but that is a topic for another research.Thanks.

Comment: You could return the set of expected next tokens resonably easily.  Or you could return a partial-AST (containing just the existing parts).  Or a list of unclosed parenthical-like tokens.  Depends on what you are trying to do.